# How can I use clip-path to achieve a text effect on my SVG in the browser?

Tags: svg, mask, clip-path

I want to use clip-path to implement effect like: [svg with text clip-path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z2A2.jpg),  but open in browser it just display an empty
svg.  I wrap the path with <g> tag, then it failed.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" style="
    width: 200px;
    height:  200px;
">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="text-path">
            <g clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd">
                <path d="M0 0H14V2H2V13H22V10H24V13H32V27H24V32H0V0ZM2 30V27H22V30H2Z"/>
                <path d="M16 0L24 8H16V0Z"/>
                <text x="7.5" y="23">PDF</text>
            </g>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#text-path)" fill="red">
        <path d="M0 0H14V2H2V13H22V10H24V13H32V27H24V32H0V0ZM2 30V27H22V30H2Z"/>
        <path d="M16 0L24 8H16V0Z"/>
    </g>

    <style>
        text {dominant-baseline: hanging;font-size: 8px;font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
</svg>
```

it should be displayed in browser.

Comment: As you've discovered a clipPath cannot contain a g tag.

Comment: thanks for  your answer,  do you know how to compose the multiple paths and use the clip-path to fill the shape but exclude the text area?

Comment: Use a mask instead, probably.

Comment: you are right, the mask is more flexible to do it. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example (above) you may remove the wrapping group around the 2 paths and the text and it would work.

```
 <clipPath id="text-path">
        <!-- <g clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"> -->
            <path d="M0 0H14V2H2V13H22V10H24V13H32V27H24V32H0V0ZM2 30V27H22V30H2Z"/>
            <path d="M16 0L24 8H16V0Z"/>
            <text x="7.5" y="23">PDF</text>
        <!-- </g> -->
 </clipPath>
```

However you won't see the text.
If what you need is to see the text as a hole in the shapes you will need a mask where the text is black and the 2 paths are white. In the case of the mask  you can use a group if you think you need it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="
    width: 200px;
    height:  200px;
    background:silver">
  <mask id="m">
  <g fill="white">
    <path d="M0 0H14V2H2V13H22V10H24V13H32V27H24V32H0V0ZM2 30V27H22V30H2Z" />
    <path d="M16 0L24 8H16V0Z" />
  </g>
    <text x="7.5" y="23" fill="black">PDF</text>
  </mask>

  <rect width="32" height="32" mask="url(#m)" fill="red" />

  <style>
    text {
      dominant-baseline: hanging;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

</svg>
```